# How to delete vertices with the same direction

Tags: qgis, editing, simplify

I have feature with a big amount of vertices. But these vertices are totally useless and make Qgis editing too slow. Lets look on image with example:

These vertices inside of black line I want to delete. But I want to **preserve shape** of red line as well. So I need to let vertex outside of black lines.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I am trying to reduce the number of vertices in some large polygon layers without changing the shape of the polygons.

Comment: @Mike there is an [accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/204078/64785) by vagvaf below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vector -> Geomtry Tools -> Simplify Geometries. You have to experiment with the tolerance though...

Otherwise you can make a custom script that checks if the azimuth of two concecutive segments is the same and in that case to delete the middle vertex.

Comment: Yes, I tried Simplify geometries, but the problem is, that for other features I need other tolerance, so I want to automatized this process. I thought it could be some script or tool for doing this. So I will need create this one. Last question. What v.generalize? Is there any chance that particular algorithm could do this work? Algorithms in doc are not well-desribed